# Why is the count 0 when I use gmail api patch label name and then get label info?

Tags: gmail-api

this problem appear occasionally
[patch label_177 name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYaH5.png)
[get label_177 label info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6qvV.png)

patch Request body
`{ "name": "Test77" }`
response
`{ "id": "Label_177", "name": "Test77", "messageListVisibility": "show", "labelListVisibility": "labelShow", "type": "user", "messagesTotal": 4, "messagesUnread": 4, "threadsTotal": 4, "threadsUnread": 4, "color": { "textColor": "#000000", "backgroundColor": "#c9daf8" } }`

get label info
`{ "id": "Label_177", "name": "Test77", "messageListVisibility": "show", "labelListVisibility": "labelShow", "type": "user", "messagesTotal": 0, "messagesUnread": 0, "threadsTotal": 0, "threadsUnread": 0, "color": { "textColor": "#000000", "backgroundColor": "#c9daf8" } }`

Any guidance would be appreciated, thank you